# CSS switch input text is not visible when background colour applied to parent element

Tags: html, forms, css, topcoat

I am looking at the topcoat library and using one of there components; Topcoat Switch.

The example functions fine here:

http://codepen.io/Topcoat/pen/upxds

But in my app I nest the switch in an unordered list and have to apply a background colour to the containing list element for styling purposes.  As mimicked here:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ekKEc

This crude example masks the text from being visible which is highly undesirable.

Similarly if i apply a background colour to the label element the same issue is evident.

Any help on this would be nice as i spent the last day messing about with z-index etc and just figured out it was the background colour.

Comment: add z-index: 2; in .topcoat-switch class in css..and check if its working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing the `z-index` on the .topcoat-switch class should do the trick.

**Check it out: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vcqGh**